# Rundeck service starts and goes to dead state after a while

Tags: haproxy, rundeck

Rundeck service starts and goes to dead state after a while

Below is the output.

```
02:43:11 # rpm -qa | grep rundeck rundeck-config-2.6.9-1.21.GA.noarch rundeck-2.6.9-1.21.GA.noarch

02:43:59 # service rundeckd start Starting rundeckd: [ OK ]

02:44:07 # service rundeckd status rundeckd (pid 31637) is running...

02:44:48 # service rundeckd status rundeckd dead but pid file exists

02:44:14 # java -version openjdk version "1.8.0_262" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_262-b10) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.262-b10, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking your original post [here](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/PqZE5_yfwQo). It's a system network problem (`java.net.BindException: Address already in use`), another process is using your Rundeck TCP port, that's the reason why the Rundeck process dead on startup. You can identify "the another" process with `lsof -i :4440` or reconfigure Rundeck to listen to another TCP port.

EDIT: Jabraj [found](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/PqZE5_yfwQo/m/8pgAVNMSDAAJ) the solution: downgrade to JDK 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and i resolved it by changing ownership to the rundeck related folders.

1. Remove the /var/run/rundeck.pid file in order to delete the zombie process.
2. Check for any other zombie process using lsof commmand.
3. Reownership the rundeck related folders (Owner should be rundeck)
4. Restart the rundeckd service.
5. Hurray!!! its running inside the container well.

[4 steps to resolve rundeck issue](https://kalaivairamuthu.wordpress.com/2021/06/30/rundeckd-stopped-after-start/)